# How to get which checkbox is clicked in JQuery

Tags: jquery

How to get which checkbox is clicked in JQuery for the following example? I don't know how to call method click when I have multiple div tags.

```
<div class="caption">
 <div class="image-title>
  <p>Image shows a nautillus shell:</p>
  <div class="cb">
    <input type="checkbox" id="yes">Yes
    <input type="checkbox" id="no">No
  </div> 
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you should better use radio buttons in this case.

Answer (score 1):

if checked:

```
var cb = $('#yes');
if (cb.is(':checked')) { /* do something */ }
```

if clicked:

```
$('#yes').click(function(){
    /* do something */
});
```

Comment: @ilija Please mark it as the correct answer if you see it so :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have given an `ID` to each `input`. You could add an event handler for each `input`:

```
$("#yes").click(function() {
   alert("yes was clicked");
});
```

Or attach more general event listener:

```
$(".cb input").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert("Clicked ID: " + id);
});
```

Although not sure why you want to use `clicked` - checkboxes use `checked` state.

Comment: This works only when I put div cb outside div caption. Otherwise it won't work. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use radio buttons in this case

```
<input type="radio" id="yes" name="status">Yes
<input type="radio" id="no" name="status">No
```

and then you can get the selected radio button value by using

```
   $('input:radio[name=status]:checked').val();
```